# Programming attiny45 chip and ir remote library

Tags: arduino-uno, attiny

I'm using the IR Remote library with an attiny45 chip. The codes works fine with an Arduino but getting error message when uploading to attiny45 chip.

```
#include <IRremote.h>

int RECV_PIN = 2;
int led = 1;
int relay = 0;

IRrecv irrecv(RECV_PIN);

decode_results results;

void setup()
{
  irrecv.enableIRIn(); // Start the receiver
  pinMode (led, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (relay, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  if (irrecv.decode(&results)) {

    switch (results.value) {
      case 0xff02fd :
        digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(relay, LOW);
        break;

        case 0x1FC42BD :
        digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(relay, LOW);
        break;

      default :
        digitalWrite(led, LOW);
        digitalWrite(relay, HIGH);
        break;
    }

    irrecv.resume(); // Receive the next value
  }
}
```

When uploading, i'm getting the following error messages :
    Arduino: 1.8.1 (Windows 7), Board: "ATtiny25/45/85, ATtiny45, Internal 8 MHz"

```
C:\Users\Acer\Documents\Arduino\libraries\IRremote\IRremote.cpp: In member function 'void IRsend::mark(int)':

C:\Users\Acer\Documents\Arduino\libraries\IRremote\IRremote.cpp:176:3: error: 'TCCR2A' was not declared in this scope

   TCCR2A |= _BV(COM2B1); // Enable pin 3 PWM output

   ^

In file included from c:\program files (x86)\arduino\hardware\tools\avr\avr\include\avr\io.h:99:0,

                 from c:\program files (x86)\arduino\hardware\tools\avr\avr\include\avr\pgmspace.h:90,

                 from C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino/Arduino.h:28,

                 from C:\Users\Acer\Documents\Arduino\libraries\IRremote\IRremoteInt.h:15,

                 from C:\Users\Acer\Documents\Arduino\libraries\IRremote\IRremote.cpp:13:

C:\Users\Acer\Documents\Arduino\libraries\IRremote\IRremote.cpp:176:17: error: 'COM2B1' was not declared in this scope

   TCCR2A |= _BV(COM2B1); // Enable pin 3 PWM output

                 ^

C:\Users\Acer\Documents\Arduino\libraries\IRremote\IRremote.cpp: In member function 'void IRsend::space(int)':

C:\Users\Acer\Documents\Arduino\libraries\IRremote\IRremote.cpp:188:3: error: 'TCCR2A' was not declared in this scope

   TCCR2A &= ~(_BV(COM2B1)); // Disable pin 3 PWM output

   ^

In file included from c:\program files (x86)\arduino\hardware\tools\avr\avr\include\avr\io.h:99:0,

                 from c:\program files (x86)\arduino\hardware\tools\avr\avr\include\avr\pgmspace.h:90,

                 from C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino/Arduino.h:28,

                 from C:\Users\Acer\Documents\Arduino\libraries\IRremote\IRremoteInt.h:15,

                 from C:\Users\Acer\Documents\Arduino\libraries\IRremote\IRremote.cpp:13:

C:\Users\Acer\Documents\Arduino\libraries\IRremote\IRremote.cpp:188:19: error: 'COM2B1' was not declared in this scope

   TCCR2A &= ~(_BV(COM2B1)); // Disable pin 3 PWM output

                   ^

C:\Users\Acer\Documents\Arduino\libraries\IRremote\IRremote.cpp: In member function 'void IRsend::enableIROut(int)':

C:\Users\Acer\Documents\Arduino\libraries\IRremote\IRremote.cpp:210:3: error: 'TIMSK2' was not declared in this scope

   TIMSK2 &= ~_BV(TOIE2); //Timer2 Overflow Interrupt

   ^

In file included from c:\program files (x86)\arduino\hardware\tools\avr\avr\include\avr\io.h:99:0,

                 from c:\program files (x86)\arduino\hardware\tools\avr\avr\include\avr\pgmspace.h:90,

                 from C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino/Arduino.h:28,

                 from C:\Users\Acer\Documents\Arduino\libraries\IRremote\IRremoteInt.h:15,

                 from C:\Users\Acer\Documents\Arduino\libraries\IRremote\IRremote.cpp:13:

C:\Users\Acer\Documents\Arduino\libraries\IRremote\IRremote.cpp:210:18: error: 'TOIE2' was not declared in this scope

   TIMSK2 &= ~_BV(TOIE2); //Timer2 Overflow Interrupt

                  ^

C:\Users\Acer\Documents\Arduino\libraries\IRremote\IRremote.cpp:228:3: error: 'TCCR2A' was not declared in this scope

   TCCR2A = _BV(WGM20);

   ^

In file included from c:\program files (x86)\arduino\hardware\tools\avr\avr\include\avr\io.h:99:0,

                 from c:\program files (x86)\arduino\hardware\tools\avr\avr\include\avr\pgmspace.h:90,

                 from C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino/Arduino.h:28,

                 from C:\Users\Acer\Documents\Arduino\libraries\IRremote\IRremoteInt.h:15,

                 from C:\Users\Acer\Documents\Arduino\libraries\IRremote\IRremote.cpp:13:

C:\Users\Acer\Documents\Arduino\libraries\IRremote\IRremote.cpp:228:16: error: 'WGM20' was not declared in this scope

   TCCR2A = _BV(WGM20);

                ^

C:\Users\Acer\Documents\Arduino\libraries\IRremote\IRremote.cpp:229:3: error: 'TCCR2B' was not declared in this scope

   TCCR2B = _BV(WGM22) | _BV(CS20);

   ^

In file included from c:\program files (x86)\arduino\hardware\tools\avr\avr\include\avr\io.h:99:0,

                 from c:\program files (x86)\arduino\hardware\tools\avr\avr\include\avr\pgmspace.h:90,

                 from C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino/Arduino.h:28,

                 from C:\Users\Acer\Documents\Arduino\libraries\IRremote\IRremoteInt.h:15,

                 from C:\Users\Acer\Documents\Arduino\libraries\IRremote\IRremote.cpp:13:

C:\Users\Acer\Documents\Arduino\libraries\IRremote\IRremote.cpp:229:16: error: 'WGM22' was not declared in this scope

   TCCR2B = _BV(WGM22) | _BV(CS20);

                ^

C:\Users\Acer\Documents\Arduino\libraries\IRremote\IRremote.cpp:229:29: error: 'CS20' was not declared in this scope

   TCCR2B = _BV(WGM22) | _BV(CS20);

                             ^

C:\Users\Acer\Documents\Arduino\libraries\IRremote\IRremote.cpp:232:3: error: 'OCR2A' was not declared in this scope

   OCR2A = SYSCLOCK / 2 / khz / 1000;

   ^

C:\Users\Acer\Documents\Arduino\libraries\IRremote\IRremote.cpp:233:3: error: 'OCR2B' was not declared in this scope

   OCR2B = OCR2A / 3; // 33% duty cycle

   ^

C:\Users\Acer\Documents\Arduino\libraries\IRremote\IRremote.cpp: In member function 'void IRrecv::enableIRIn()':

C:\Users\Acer\Documents\Arduino\libraries\IRremote\IRremote.cpp:262:3: error: 'TCCR2A' was not declared in this scope

   TCCR2A = 0;  // normal mode

   ^

In file included from c:\program files (x86)\arduino\hardware\tools\avr\avr\include\avr\io.h:99:0,

                 from c:\program files (x86)\arduino\hardware\tools\avr\avr\include\avr\pgmspace.h:90,

                 from C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino/Arduino.h:28,

                 from C:\Users\Acer\Documents\Arduino\libraries\IRremote\IRremoteInt.h:15,

                 from C:\Users\Acer\Documents\Arduino\libraries\IRremote\IRremote.cpp:13:

C:\Users\Acer\Documents\Arduino\libraries\IRremote\IRremote.cpp:267:7: error: 'TCCR2B' was not declared in this scope

   cbi(TCCR2B,CS22);

       ^

C:\Users\Acer\Documents\Arduino\libraries\IRremote\IRremote.cpp:267:3: note: in expansion of macro 'cbi'

   cbi(TCCR2B,CS22);

   ^

Multiple libraries were found for "IRremote.h"
C:\Users\Acer\Documents\Arduino\libraries\IRremote\IRremote.cpp:267:14: error: 'CS22' was not declared in this scope

 Used: C:\Users\Acer\Documents\Arduino\libraries\IRremote
   cbi(TCCR2B,CS22);

 Not used: C:\Users\Acer\Documents\Arduino\libraries\IRremote1
              ^

 Not used: C:\Users\Acer\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Arduino-IRremote-master
C:\Users\Acer\Documents\Arduino\libraries\IRremote\IRremote.cpp:267:3: note: in expansion of macro 'cbi'

   cbi(TCCR2B,CS22);

   ^

C:\Users\Acer\Documents\Arduino\libraries\IRremote\IRremote.cpp:268:14: error: 'CS21' was not declared in this scope

   sbi(TCCR2B,CS21);

              ^

C:\Users\Acer\Documents\Arduino\libraries\IRremote\IRremote.cpp:268:3: note: in expansion of macro 'sbi'

   sbi(TCCR2B,CS21);

   ^

C:\Users\Acer\Documents\Arduino\libraries\IRremote\IRremote.cpp:269:14: error: 'CS20' was not declared in this scope

   cbi(TCCR2B,CS20);

              ^

C:\Users\Acer\Documents\Arduino\libraries\IRremote\IRremote.cpp:269:3: note: in expansion of macro 'cbi'

   cbi(TCCR2B,CS20);

   ^

C:\Users\Acer\Documents\Arduino\libraries\IRremote\IRremote.cpp:272:7: error: 'TIMSK2' was not declared in this scope

   sbi(TIMSK2,TOIE2);

       ^

C:\Users\Acer\Documents\Arduino\libraries\IRremote\IRremote.cpp:272:3: note: in expansion of macro 'sbi'

   sbi(TIMSK2,TOIE2);

   ^

C:\Users\Acer\Documents\Arduino\libraries\IRremote\IRremote.cpp:272:14: error: 'TOIE2' was not declared in this scope

   sbi(TIMSK2,TOIE2);

              ^

C:\Users\Acer\Documents\Arduino\libraries\IRremote\IRremote.cpp:272:3: note: in expansion of macro 'sbi'

   sbi(TIMSK2,TOIE2);

   ^

In file included from C:\Users\Acer\Documents\Arduino\libraries\IRremote\IRremote.cpp:13:0:

C:\Users\Acer\Documents\Arduino\libraries\IRremote\IRremoteInt.h:46:24: error: 'TCNT2' was not declared in this scope

   #define RESET_TIMER2 TCNT2 = INIT_TIMER_COUNT2

                        ^

C:\Users\Acer\Documents\Arduino\libraries\IRremote\IRremote.cpp:278:3: note: in expansion of macro 'RESET_TIMER2'

   RESET_TIMER2;

   ^

C:\Users\Acer\Documents\Arduino\libraries\IRremote\IRremote.cpp: In function 'void __vector_5()':

C:\Users\Acer\Documents\Arduino\libraries\IRremote\IRremoteInt.h:46:24: error: 'TCNT2' was not declared in this scope

   #define RESET_TIMER2 TCNT2 = INIT_TIMER_COUNT2

                        ^

C:\Users\Acer\Documents\Arduino\libraries\IRremote\IRremote.cpp:308:3: note: in expansion of macro 'RESET_TIMER2'

   RESET_TIMER2;

   ^

exit status 1
Error compiling for board ATtiny25/45/85.

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

This is the version of Arduino that i'm using :
    Arduino: 1.8.1 (Windows 7), Board: "ATtiny25/45/85, ATtiny45, Internal 8 MHz"

Comment: You probably can't use pin 3 (the _BV(bit) macro) because IRremote library uses Timer 2 in a mode that only works with output on Arduino Pin 3. Take a look on this Instructable: http://www.instructables.com/id/Attiny-IR-library/?ALLSTEPS

Comment: Pin 3 means which pin on the attiny please?

Comment: Yes it's Pin 3 on Arduino UNO and it's hardcoded.

Comment: I'm not using pin 3 on the Arduino Uno, the code I uploaded is the Attiny45. On the Arduino Uno, i'm using the pin 9

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure this has problem has to be the fact when downloading to an attiny45 or any Arduino-like-chip you need to reset the chip as code is being downloaded. The reset pin is pin 1. To reset it you should ground the pin. [Here](http://highlowtech.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/ATtiny45-85.png) is the pinout diagram for reference.